# FPGA bitstream analysis mismatch

Tags: fpga

I'm using XDL file to analyze the bitstream of a spartan3e FPGA, I did the following steps:

1. I set up a single PIP for the XDL file and generate the bitstream file.
2. I set up a entirely empty XDL file with no PIPs in it and generate the bitstream file.
3. Compare the above two bitstreams bit by bit.

I do the above steps to all the PIPs in the FPGA to get a database of all the PIPs. however, when I tried to scan a normal FPGA design bitstream with this PIP database, I found inconsistency. for example: the following PIP:

pip CLB_X15Y7 OMUX2 -> BX0,

is not in the XDL description of the normal FPGA design, but all the 3 corresponding positions in the bitstream are "ON", which will cause a false positive detection of this PIP.

I feel very confused about this situation.

Comment: You're using one undocumented interface to try to decipher another undocumented interface? I think you're pretty much on your own with this one! I don't know anything about how Xilinx FPGA routing resources are configured at the bit level, but it really doesn't surprise me that different "pip"s share bits in the bitstream.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, Thanks for your reply. i do hope i could get some help, even if some clues. according to my previous work, your point is correct, some PIPs indeed share bits, but they never be exactly the same. that is to say normally the situation is still under control, i can handle it. but for the problem i described in this title. i got a completely wrong PIP, when i checked the design's XDL file, this PIP actually doesn't exist, i don't know why the three corresponding bits are turned on, which made me felt something must be wrong, but i just can't explain it...

Comment: It would be prudent (than being lazy) to properly capitalize / punctuate your question properly!

Comment: It's clear that you are trying to develop a tool that will assist with reverse-engineering the functionality of an FPGA from its bitstream. There are many ethical and legal problems associated with doing this, and the few people in the world who are doing it try to avoid doing it in a public forum. Furthermore, as you have seen, it takes a lot of work, and even fewer people are going to give away their hard-won information for free. In any case, even if what you are doing is legitimate, it's off-topic here, since it's more of an information theory or mathematical issue.

Comment: @ChetanBhargava: If you are going to criticize the form rather than the content of a post, it would be prudent to post comments that don't include similar problems!

Comment: Have you read the publications (>5) from "Dirk Koch"? He does strange things with dynamic reconfiguration, XDL files and so on. [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/researcher/75036739_Dirk_Koch), [DBLP](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/pers/hd/k/Koch:Dirk)

Comment: @Dave Tweed thanks for your direction, yes i know this could be potentially illegal, i just want to gather some legally published clues.

Comment: @Paebbels thanks for your direction, i will check his work to see if it provides any clue on my problem, thank you very much!

Comment: @DaveTweed It was a suggestion to the new user not a criticism.

Comment: @DaveTweed *it's off-topic here, since it's more of an information theory or mathematical issue*. No it's not. The question is about implementation details of an FPGA. Xilinx itself released XDL as a low-level language to debug and edit FPGA configurations. Additionally, the provide tools to convert netlists to XDL and back.

Comment: @Paebbels: Yes, I understand that. But Xilinx doesn't document or support it, and this discussion about the language and how it maps to the bitstreams is not really about the design of the chips themselves, nor about the applications that the chips are used for. It's about the software tools used to support those activities. Hence, information theory, not EE.